# Not able to get Location

Tags: android, location

I am not able to access the location, but once the location is changed using the mock apps the app works fine using the on-location changed method.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


        }

        else{

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 , 0 , locationListener);

            Location locationlast = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            longView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longView);
            latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latView);
            accView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accView);
            altView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altView);
            addView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addView);

            altView.setText(String.valueOf("Altitude: " +locationlast.getAltitude()));
            accView.setText(String.valueOf("Accuracy: "+locationlast.getAccuracy()));
            latView.setText(String.valueOf("Latitude: "+locationlast.getLatitude()));
            longView.setText(String.valueOf("Longitude: " + locationlast.getLongitude()));

             Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationlast.getLatitude(),locationlast.getLongitude(), 1);
                if(addresses != null && addresses.size() >0){
                    String address = "";
                    if(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null){
                        address += addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare().toString() + "\n";
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null){
                        address += addresses.get(0).getLocality().toString() +": ";
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode()!= null){

                        address += addresses.get(0).getPostalCode().toString()+ "\n";
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null){

                        address += addresses.get(0).getAdminArea().toString() + "\n";
                    }
                    if(addresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null){
                        address += addresses.get(0).getCountryName().toString();
                    }
                    addView.setText("Address: \n" + address);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Did you check your GPS or location? It should turn on.

Comment: get permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION also

Comment: better use GoogleApiClient to get current location.

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation` may return null before it actually finds your location through GPS. This case you should use listener

Comment: I have used the listener but it gets be a return value only when my Location is changed, but when I start the application over the device it cannot detect my current location and pops up a screen with application has stopped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You used below class to get current location and show marker on that.

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapLocationActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

}
```